# how to use tilemap in kibana with key & token

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, mapquest

Map visualizations not working anymore in kibana. Looks like since 11 july the map visualizations are not working anymore. Only error messages are displayed. This is caused by a change of rules by MapQuest.
direct tile access of mapQuest has been discontinued.
so how can i use mapQuest in Kibana visualizations Chart with API Key & Token

attaching here snapshot of that error. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.
Just wait for update from elasticsearch team
[You can follow here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/map-visualizations-have-stopped-working-due-to-mapquest-change-july-11-2016/55231/4)

The solution is now released [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-5-3-and-4-1-10/)